# Looking for a method to convert to bitmap an image with MultipartUploadRequest

Tags: android, image, bitmap, upload, type-conversion

As a new into programming, i think this website is awesome!

I'm using the library MultipartUploadRequest to upload an image into a server, but i struggle to find a way to use bitmap argument instead of string for .addFileToUpload parameter.

the argument exptected are:

```
MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload( path, "image") 
                    .addParameter("name", name) 
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload();
```

Since i want to upload bitmap file, i'm looking for a method to change the argument "path" to "bitmap".

is it possibile?

Thank you to everyone!

Comment: It comes from "net.gotev.uploadservice.MultipartUploadRequest" library.

Answer (score 0):

According to this library, you should the path string of the file you want to upload so you need to save your bitmap to a file then upload this file.
1. save Bitmap to a file in a location:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File file = new File(path + "/image_name.jpg"); 
OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
pictureBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut); // saving the Bitmap to a file compressed as a JPEG with 85% compression rate
fOut.flush(); // Not really required
fOut.close(); // do not forget to close the stream
```

2. upload your file:

```
MultipartUploadRequest(this, uploadId, Constants.UPLOAD_URL)
                    .addFileToUpload( path+"/image_name.jpg", "image") 
                    .addParameter("name", name) 
                    .setNotificationConfig(new UploadNotificationConfig())
                    .setMaxRetries(2)
                    .startUpload();
```

Note: do not forget to grantee the write and read external storage permissions.